# How to retrieve just the generic items from credentials using CredentialManager

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve just the generic credentials from:

```cs
using CredentialManagement;

// ...

CredentialSet credentialSet = new CredentialSet();
credentialSet.Load();

// Setup generic credentials subset
CredentialSet genericCredentialSet = (CredentialSet)credentialSet.Where(x => x.Type == CredentialType.Generic);  //if I set this to var it works
```

I would like to store as `CredentialSet` (not `var`). I am getting a cast error with the above code.

Here is how the CredentialSet class begins:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CredentialManagement
{
    public class CredentialSet: List<Credential>, IDisposable
    {
        bool _disposed;

        public CredentialSet()
        {
        }

        public CredentialSet(string target)
            : this()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(target))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
            }
            Target = target;
        }

        public string Target { get; set; }
...
```

References:
[CredentialManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you posted, and so assuming `CredentialSet` really inherits `List<Credential>` like the code you posted says, then all you need is to call `AddRange()`. I.e.

```cs
CredentialSet genericCredentialSet = new CredentialSet();

genericCredentialSet.AddRange(credentialSet.Where(x => x.Type == CredentialType.Generic));
```

Alternatively, if you are up for forking or contributing to [the repo where you found `CredentialSet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement/), add a new constructor that accepts `IEnumerable<Credential>`:

```cs
public CredentialSet(IEnumerable<Credential> credentials) : base(credentials)
{ }
```

Which you can then use like:

```cs
CredentialSet genericCredentialSet = new CredentialSet(credentialSet.Where(x => x.Type == CredentialType.Generic));
```

Yet another alternative, and again, only if you are willing to modify the `CredentialSet` class itself, you could add [an explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) so that the cast syntax you tried would work:

```cs
public class CredentialSet: List<Credential>, IDisposable
{
    // ... other class members ...

    public static explicit operator CredentialSet(IEnumerable<Credential> credentials)
    {
        CredentialSet credentialSet = new CredentialSet();
    
        credentialSet.AddRange(credentials);

        return credentialSet;
    }
}
```

Naturally, you could combine the constructor alternative with the user-defined conversion operator alternative to simplify the syntax used in the implementation of the user-defined conversion operator.

Regardless of how you implement the user-defined conversion operator, doing so would allow this code you had in the first place to actually compile successfully:

```cs
CredentialSet genericCredentialSet = (CredentialSet)credentialSet.Where(x => x.Type == CredentialType.Generic);
```